# How to compare digits with date PHP

Tags: php, date

Is there a way to convert values to date? I have 3 dropdown lists: day, month and year. If the selected date < today, then the consumers won't be able to click on the buy button til the day i selected in de dropdown.
The problem is, that the date I selected, is a value and not a date. Is there a way to compare my value with the date of today? The code below is the backend of my website, the if statement has to stay on the frontend

```
    $releasedatumdag= get_post_meta( $domeinnaam_extensies->ID, 'releasedatumdag', true );
$releasedatummaand= get_post_meta( $domeinnaam_extensies->ID, 'releasedatummaand', true );
$releasedatumjaar= get_post_meta( $domeinnaam_extensies->ID, 'releasedatumjaar', true );

<tr>
        <th>Releasedatum:</th>
        <td>
            <select name="domeinnaam_extensies_releasedatumdag">
                <?php
                for($idag = 1; $idag <= 31; $idag++){
                echo '<option value="'.$idag.'">'.$idag.'</option>';
                                                        }
                ?>
            </select>

            <select name="domeinnaam_extensies_releasedatummaand">
                <?php
                for($imaand = 1; $imaand <= 12; $imaand++){
                echo '<option value="'.$imaand.'">'.$imaand.'</option>';
                                                        }
                ?>
            </select>

            <select name="domeinnaam_extensies_releasedatumjaar">
                <?php
                for($ijaar = 2000; $ijaar < date("Y")+10; $ijaar++){
                echo '<option value="'.$ijaar.'">'.$ijaar.'</option>';
                                                        }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Yes. Show us  a sample date value your form produces.

Comment: You have 3 parts to build a date. Validate them then join together. Even you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php to convert them to date objects.

Comment: What do you mean John? i got 3 lists, sample: 31/12/2014

Comment: See also, HTML5 date select and jQuery validation

Comment: No, i have to this with php... I'm changing a wordpress module

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime()` to create your date. You then can compare it to another DateTime object representing today since DateTime objects are comparable:

```
$my_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/12/2014');
$now     = new DateTime();
if ($my_date < $now) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a day, month, and a year so just create a `DateTime` object and you can get the timestamp for it and compare it to today.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

```
Can string the digits into any format that you want
$dateString = $releasedatumdag . '/' . $releasedatummaand . '/' . $releasedatumjaar;

//Make sure that they didn't try to create Feb. 31
if(checkdate($dateString)) {
    $submittedTime = new DateTime($dateString);
    $today = new DateTime();

    //DO YOUR COMPARISON HERE
}
```